# parsing array requests in Python

Tags: python, arrays, parsing

Is there a common way to parse arrays sent in this notation?

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('a=1&a=2')['a']
['1', '2']
```

I'd expect the output of the following to be the same:

```
>>> urlparse.parse_qs('a[0]=1&a[1]=2')['a']
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'a'
```

Is there a reason why it isn't so?

Comment: Probably because that's a very unusual way of constructing a query string. Where is it coming from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm seeing it while using mootools: `var arr=[1,2]; new Request({url:'...'}).post({a: arr});`

Answer (score 3):

Why would you expect the results from two entirely different query strings to be the same? You have two distinct keys in the your second query string: `a[0]` and `a[1]`. They are strings and `urlparse` does not further parse them. You will find them in the resulting dictionary under the names by which they appear in the query string.

If `urlparse` behaved as you seem to want it to, how would this be parsed?

```
a=1&a=2&a[0]=3&a[1]=4
```

Comment: Semantically they are both array notations seen on the web. Your example I'd expect to be parsed as `['3', '4', '1', '2']`.